# How to connect to docker-compose port from docker and locally?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am using spring boot 2.5.3 and postgreSQL for backend.

I want this app to run on `localhost:5000/api/v1/customers` as well as from docker-compose.

application.properties:

```
server.port=5000
#Database setup
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customers
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

This works with localhost, with `mvn spring-boot:run`

But, when I use the following application.properties settings from `localhost` to `db`

```
server.port=5000
#Database setup
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customers
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-11-slim
COPY ./target/customer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: customer-container
    image: customer-image:v1
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=customers
```

I cannot connect to `localhost:5000/api/v1/customers` after `mvn spring-boot:run`
Error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
```

Tried to create a docker image  `docker build -t customer-image:v1 .`
, and run `docker-compose build` `docker-compose up` there are no error.
Logs says it is running on port 5000.

```
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.053  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.068  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.069  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.189  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.190  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1876 ms
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.487  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.567  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.702  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.827  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.970  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:42.995  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:43.631  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:43.631  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "customer" does not exist, skipping
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:43.642  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:43.656  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:44.252  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:44.991  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
customer-container | 2021-08-29 12:43:45.290  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.p.customer.CustomerApplication         : Started CustomerApplication in 5.654 seconds (JVM running for 6.531)
```

This works `localhost:5000/api/v1/customers` when docker-compose is up.

Is there a way we can have condtional name for host in this line?Is there any other way?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the host development environment and the container runtime environment are different, you can use environment variables to differentiate between them.  Spring Boot knows how to [set Spring properties from environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding).  So I'd recommend:

- In your `application.properties` file, set `spring.datasource.url` to the `localhost` URL you'd use in development.
- In your Compose setup, set the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable to the name specific to that Compose setup

  ```yaml
  version: '3.8'
  services:
     db: { ... }
     app:
       environment:
         - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customers
       ...
  ```
- Do not create a separate Spring profile per environment; you would not want to recompile your jar file if you changed the database name or password, or deployed this in Kubernetes, or used a cloud-hosted database like Amazon RDS, or...

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to be able to run both locally and from docker?

If that's the case, you need to extract the database connection string to an environment variable that you set at runtime

```
spring.datasource.url = ${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/
spring.datasource.username = ${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${DB_PASSWD}
```

Or you can introduce two different property files that get set from a Spring profile, which you also would set at runtime; Refer `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to run locally and on docker. Reading about having different profiles and will try doing that for next project.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I see, you are not supposed to use localhost on spring.datasource.url because your docker is within the container itself, you should be using
`jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/customers` instead. For more details, you can view from this link https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers

`Is there a way we can have condtional name for host in this line?Is there any other way?`
As for this, it would be prefered to set it as an environmetn variable on your docker compose file and connect using dbconn url

Answer (score -1):

If you are using linux as your operating system on which you are running your docker , you can set this property
network_mode: host

on both the containers, this will attach your container's port to your localhost port.
You will need to remove the port forwarding config for this to work.

Comment: There's no reason to disable Docker networking for this straightforward setup.