# Can I change a database depending on the branch I am on (specified in Dockerfile)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, branch

I would like to have my:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://666.666.666.666/prod_very_wow
```

Change into:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://666.666.666.666/dev_very_wow
```

According to the branch I am currently on. I think I should also have it specified within the Dockerfile - I should have a property added next to docker's RUN which should determine which data source ought to be activated.

Namely, I would like my app to be connected to prod_very_wow when I am on master branch and dev_very_wow everytime I am checking out to dev or creating a new feature branch and have it all determined by a property added to RUN mvn package within the Dockerfile.

I apologise if the question makes no sense, but, frankly - I am a little bit clueless how to ask this question and so I have troubles googling for answers.
I just found a couple of leads about "environmental variables", but I can't find any connection between the datasource connected to and the branch I am currently on.

Comment: I would not recommend including database URLs or names directly in your source tree, and especially not in the Dockerfile.  I wrote up [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68973314) yesterday discussing how to use environment variables to set the Spring database URL in a Docker Compose context.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked into it, but I am not sure if I understand the usage od Docker Compose correctly. I do not currently have one in the project. Does it function like a manager of sorts for Dockerfiles?

Comment: Yes.  If you'd normally `docker build` a custom image or two, `docker network create` and `docker volume create`, and then `docker run` some containers, Compose manages that sequence of steps for you.

Comment: Thank you for the time and information. I will look into the subject of Docker Compose in this case. Albeit currently I have utilized Spring Profiles (two application.properties files), two Dockerfiles (each of whom with the CMD to run a certain profile - one of them having --spring.profiles.active=prod) and two Jenkinsfiles to match. So now the pipeline recevies the name of the correct Jenkinfile to run now. I reckon Docker Compose's usage would make it more optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle different configuration based on environment is to have decoupled your code from your configuration that is one of the twelve-factor apps principles. In this case you should have an external config server, like spring cloud config server, that will host the configurations files for the different environments and the application will ask this config server for the proper config file depending on the environment where it is deployed.

However, if you don't want to follow this approach you can create the different configuration files in the application and use an environment variable that tells spring which file to use. For example, in your case you can have an application-local.yaml and application-prod.yaml, and then if you want to specify it in the dockerfile in the mvn package command, you can use:

```
RUN mvn -Dspring.profiles.activ=local package
RUN mvn -Dspring.profiles.activ=prod package
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and looking into my issue. I am not sure if the external config server solution would be feasable, but I will consult it with my mentor. About the second one - I'd have relocate the spring.datasource.url from application.properties to a newly created application.yaml and create a second one for a second database, is that right? But I think I still don't understand how would this solution allow for the change to occur based on the branch I am working on (master or dev/feature). Is it possible to achieve it? Or did you answer it and I am simply missing it?

Comment: I have re-read your question and I think I have got it completely, so you can determine at build time (when you generate you docker image) what have to be the environment based on the gitlab branch. I don't know if this is possible. I would say no because the code inside the repository is not aware what is the branch in which it is hosted. I think the solution to this is to have this information outside the repository in the environment itself where the service should be deployed and there you can define which environment is prod indepent on the branch where the code is hosted

Comment: Thank you again for your time. When I have exhausted all my possibilities, I will consult with my mentor and, most likely - mark your take on this as an answer. :)

Comment: Hey, my case took a little bit of a turn, so I will mark your input as an answer (for steering me in the right direction) and create a second post.